# asp.net multi-row update with gridview control without looping (vb.net)

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, sqldatasource, bulk

I'm pretty new to asp.net. I'm building my first real app as a test. using SQL Server 2008 RS, VS Express 2012, IIS7.x and asp.net4.0

We receive Fedex shipment info every night that gets inserted into an MSSQL DB using SSIS. We then import the invoice, do variance matching and book costs to jobs based on the job no in Ref1 field. All this works great. However, the shipping department are supposed to put the ONLY the JobNo in the ref1 field. Of course they don't and there a lot of temps and shipping stations, so we need to fix the data. They'll put JobNo followed by junk, or junk and then the job no. When the costing people are looking at the invoice it's usually obvious what the job no is (e.g. "Samples for job 123" should be "123"). There can be many rows with the same Ref1 that needs editing (e.g 20 cartons with same Ref1). I have an SP with 3 params (OldRef, NewRef, invNo) that updates the Ref no for all records on that invoices:

```
    UPDATE InvoiceLines
    SET REF1 = @NewRef1
    WHERE InvNo = @InvNo and Ref1 = @OldRef1
```

I figured a GridView (with an sqldatasource) would be a nice way to present the data. I only show rows where the Ref1 field is invalid, as the user corrects them, the no of records reduces.

I want the user to select a row, edit the Ref1 value and I'd just get the (old) RefNo of the selected row, it's new value, and call my SP with those and the InvNo (from a DropDown that filtered the invoice lines table).

Turns out to be way more difficult/inefficient that I thought.

All the examples I found to do this type of thing, make the user click all the rows and them loop through every row to do an update. Talk about slow and painful. I want to execute a single SP and have all matching rows updated and then refresh the list.

So what I'd like to figure out is how to get the OLD Ref1 (value in Ref1 before the edit - like deleted in an SQL trigger), the NEW Ref1 (edited value that the user typed in Ref1 - like inserted in an SQL trigger) and execute my SP and then refresh the table with the updated value result set.

Am I better off with something other than a grid view, or just using something other than the built in Edit command?

If I do figure out how to do the update, how do I refresh the GridView.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

On another note, I'm on the fence about switching to C#. Most of the examples I'm finding are in C#. I learned C++ many years ago and read up on C# at weekend. It doesn't seem too difficult. I did find a Microsoft white paper and it pretty much said there's little difference between VB and C# so no real reason to switch. My colleagues do not know C or C#, so I'm just a bit concerned that in the unlikely event they need to help out, they'll be stuck. Any thoughts on this?

Regards

Mark

Comment: Does your job number follow a pattern, something like, 123 then followed by date and then some characters i.e. 12311122012ABC? Once you establish this pattern then you can have an intelligent stored procedure to identify the job no accurately and delete everything else from Ref1 field. You would not be needing an user interface.

Comment: afraid not. Currently it's a 5 digit number (so could easily be mistaken for a zip code). We'll be moving to a different job numbering scheme in 2013, but still numeric only. One detail I didn't add is that the user can enter multiple numbers (e.g. 12345, 67890) and we can handle that and split costs.

Comment: If you have MS Access, that could also be an option. It has the ability to see SQL Server tables and you can easily create forms in it to manipulate data.

Comment: Were trying to move away from MS Access; hence, the plan to do in ASP.NET